# How to subtract timestamps in postgres and get the result in seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to group data with `groupdate` like this:

```
TimeEntry.from(time_entries.select('upper(time) - lower(time) AS duration, created_at')).group_by_day(:created_at).sum(:duration)
```

The result is a hash with items like this:

```
Thu, 24 Mar 2016 00:00:00 UTC => "10:19:37"
```

My problem is, I want the duration to be in seconds (as float) instead of a string "hh:mm:ss", how can I achieve this?

I've tried `upper(time)::float` but it throws a parsing exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `EXTRACT` with `EPOCH` in your `select` statement:

```
time_entries.select("EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (UPPER(time) - LOWER(time)))")
```

Relevant docs with example: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT